# CSS - Flex-direction: column; does not create a column

Tags: css

I am creating a section in a website with three divs. I'm displaying the divs in one line with display flex and orientation row.

To make the design responsive, I want it to appear as a column as the screen size decreases. In the media query, I'm setting the container to flex-direction: column; but it's not working as intended. Two divs appear in a column, while the middle one is on the side. I have no idea why it is not working when in my last project I did the same thing and had no issues. Link to the code below so you can see what I wrote:

https://codepen.io/DanDiaz/pen/PopmOdq

```
  .grid {
    height: 95vh;
    padding-top: 5vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
```

Comment: Because of the height of 95vh. When the inner child cannot be fitted in that height, the next one will be placed in the next column. If you simply want a vertical layout just use `display: block` and the child elements to have 100% width at narrow viewport widths.

Comment: I tried increasing the height of the container and also decreasing the size of the children div (with transform scale) and the item disposition remained the same. Display block did work, however, I need to keep that in mind for next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thats due to the 'flex-wrap: wrap' on class .grid!
If you remove this property, it works :) Just need to set the proper image height then.

Comment: That did the trick! I could swear I tried that before with no results... Thanks for the help, it was starting to drive me crazy.